# How to use any JavaScript graphic libraries with MeteorJS data

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'd like to build a small MeteorJS application, which contains a bar chart, which needs to be updated any time that the underlying MongoDB data changes.
Usually, most of the graphic libraries rely on JSON array as their "local" data sources. If I have to use such an array, how can I associate it with a Mongo collection, and make the array values update any time that collection changes?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read about `Tracker.autorun` and `observeChanges` yet?

Comment: I have not read that. Will read now.

Answer (score 0):

While looking at https://forums.meteor.com, I have found a complete working example, which illustrates the solution to my problem. Here is the specific thread: https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-how-to-draw-bar-chart-using-highcharts-and-mongodb-data-reactively/5156/17 , in which user jhuenges pints to the following meteorpad example:  http://meteorpad.com/pad/iNfXQwMW3RwrokTe8/Chart

The key elements of this solution:
1) The 'data' element for the Chart is defined as a variable, who's values come from Mongo cursor:

```
series: [{
            name: 'No. of Patients',
            data: data

        }]

Template.agecolumn.onRendered(function() {  
     Tracker.autorun(function () {
    var data = Data.find({symptoms: {$in: ["Vomiting"]}}).fetch();
```

This combination insures, that, at any time, when the server-based MongoDB is updated, the values within 'data' are refreshed, and the Chart is re-rendered.

I have tested this by connecting my RoboMango utility to the server-side instance of MongoDB, and changing/removing values directly from the database.
As soon as any such change was applied to the server-side Mongo, the front-end Chart was refreshed automatically to reflect the changes, which is exactly what I was looking for.
As Christian Fritz suggested in his reply to my initial question, Tracker.autorun was used to facilitate the desired result.